# wsdl /sharetypes in Mono 2.8

Tags: .net, web-services, mono, wsdl

I'm having an issue using `wsdl /sharetypes` in Mono 2.8

I always get the following error:

`Error: Could not find file "/sharetypes".`

When I run `wsdl`, I also notice that there isn't a `sharetypes` option:

```
Web Services Description Language Utility
Mono Framework v4.0.30319.1
wsdl [options] {path | URL} {path | URL} ...

   -d, -domain:domain           Domain of username for server authentication.
   -l, -language:language       Language of generated code. Allowed CS (default)
                                and VB. You can also specify the fully qualified
                                name of a class that implements the
                                System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider Class.
   -n, -namespace:ns            The namespace of the generated code, default
                                namespace if none.
   -nologo                      Surpress the startup logo.
   -o, -out:filename            The target file for generated code.
   -p, -password:pwd            Password used to contact the server.
   -protocol:protocol           Protocol to implement. Allowed: Soap (default),
                                HttpGet or HttpPost.
   -fields                      Generate fields instead of properties in data
                                classes.
   -server                      Generate server instead of client proxy code.
   -u, -username:username       Username used to contact the server.
   -proxy:url                   Address of the proxy.
   -pu, -proxyusername:username Username used to contact the proxy.
   -pp, -proxypassword:pwd      Password used to contact the proxy.
   -pd, -proxydomain:domain     Domain of username for proxy authentication.
   -urlkey, -appsettingurlkey:key Configuration key that contains the default
                                url for the generated WS proxy.
   -baseurl, -appsettingbaseurl:url Base url to use when constructing the
                                service url.
   -sample:[binding/]operation  Display a sample SOAP request and response.
   -?                           Display this message

Options can be of the forms  -option, --option or /option
```

How can I use `/sharetypes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Mono wsdl.exe does not have that option.

Let the .Net one generate your classes and use them.

Comment: Looks like that's my only option. Really odd that mono doesn't support this option.